# How to set space between interval on axis oxyplot

Tags: c#, oxyplot

I'm working with Oxyplot to draw an image using image annotation. I need to set axis interval space so that the image looks stretch. Here what I mean by set the axis interval space

This the normal space

[image: Normal space]

and this is how I want it

[image: After set the axis interval space]

I got it from an application. How can I achieve that with Oxyplot?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stretch it horizontally use `Width` property:

```
plotModel.Annotations.Add(new ImageAnnotation
{
    ImageSource = oxyImage,
    Opacity = 0.15,
    OffsetX = new PlotLength(0, PlotLengthUnit.RelativeToPlotArea),
    OffsetY = new PlotLength(0, PlotLengthUnit.RelativeToPlotArea),
    //Height = new PlotLength(0.5, PlotLengthUnit.RelativeToPlotArea),
    Width = new PlotLength(0.5, PlotLengthUnit.RelativeToViewport),
});
```

If you comment heigth or width line, the image will scale at the same time than the plot.